# magento pdo_mysql extension is not installed in magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I'm getting this error after moving the application to another host. It's working locally, without any problems, but the issue started after moving to the webhost.  Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
pdo_mysql extension is not installed

Trace:
#0 D:\Hosting\11486590\html\shopping\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(459): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#1 D:\Hosting\11486590\html\shopping\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#2 D:\Hosting\11486590\html\shopping\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#3 D:\Hosting\11486590\html\shopping\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource.php(169): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#4 D:\Hosting\11486590\html\shopping\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#5 D:\Hosting\11486590\html\shopping\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#6 D:\Hosting\11486590\html\shopping\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#7 D:\Hosting\11486590\html\shopping\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#8 D:\Hosting\11486590\html\shopping\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Cache.php(53): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#9 D:\Hosting\11486590\html\shopping\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Cache.php(455): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Cache->getAllOptions()
#10 D:\Hosting\11486590\html\shopping\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Cache.php(497): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_initOptions()
#11 D:\Hosting\11486590\html\shopping\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1183): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->canUse('config')
#12 D:\Hosting\11486590\html\shopping\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_App->useCache('config')
#13 D:\Hosting\11486590\html\shopping\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(294): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_canUseCacheForInit()
#14 D:\Hosting\11486590\html\shopping\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(413): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache()
#15 D:\Hosting\11486590\html\shopping\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#16 D:\Hosting\11486590\html\shopping\magento\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#17 D:\Hosting\11486590\html\shopping\magento\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#18 {main}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check of your server has the pdo_mysql extension installed.

Create a file info.php and in it write `<?php phpinfo() ?>`

access the file with your browser and search for "pdo"

if not found install it or ask your server administrator to install it for you